# How to scroll top UITextview "on UITableViewCell"

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, uitextview, custom-cell

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
..
    //this cell is custom cell.
    [cell.textview setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES]; //did not work
..
}
```

////////////////

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(CustomCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ..
    [cell.textview setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES]; //did not work
    ..
    }
```

all of them not effect. textview scroll was shown bottom.

**I got it myself**

solution here.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(CouponCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, cell.textview.frame.size.height - cell.textview.contentSize.height);
    if (cell.textview.contentSize.height >= cell.textview.bounds.size.height) {
        [cell.textview setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:NO];
    }else{
        [cell.textview setContentOffset: CGPointMake(0,0) animated:NO];
    }
}
```

scrolled positon is set (0,0) by iOS inner...maybe.
so setting **minus** y values.

thanks for answer.
have a good day all!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use without animation

```
[cell.textview setContentOffset:CGPointZero]
```

Or add animation block

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [cell.textview setContentOffset:CGPointZero]
}];
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
[cell.textview scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
```

OR

```
[cell.textview setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack that works well. In cellForRow you disable textView scrolling. Then in viewDidAppear you find the specific index path that contains the textView and you enable scrolling again. If you want you can delete padding from textView:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0];
FileInfoNotesTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.notesTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;

//I cut the padding from the textview
cell.notesTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```